# CSS column layout hide empty columns

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I've done a few things with css columns and I really like them, but today I stumbled into a problem for which I just won't find a solution:

I have a page with multiple lists. These lists have dynamic contents and open up in small popups. The old behaviour was, that the list contents have been shown in a single column (normal HTML `<ul>`). The new behaviour should be that they are displayed in up to 4 columns. So I have extended my CSS with `ul { column-count: 4; }`. This works pretty nice for lists with many entries.

Now to my problem: sometimes there are lists with less then 4 entries. If that's the case, the popups for the lists still span 4 columns, with only 2 columns filled. So the popup for the less-filled list is still as wide as a popup with a full-filled list. For example:

```css
ul {
  background-color: lime;
  list-style: none;
  column-count: 4;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>entry 1</li>
<li>entry 2</li>
<li>entry 3</li>
<li>entry 4</li>
<li>entry 5</li>
<li>entry 6</li>
<li>entry 7</li>
<li>entry 8</li>
<li>entry 9</li>
<li>entry 10</li>
<li>entry 11</li>
<li>entry 12</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>entry 1</li>
<li>entry 2</li>
</ul>
```

My question now is: **How do I hide those empty columns?** I want a popup with a less filled list (no. of entries < 4) to be less wide then a popup with a full-filled list. I'd like to find a **CSS-only** solution, as I didn't intend to count the entries and add extra classes to decrease the column-count.

**The order in which the elements are displayed is important: top-down and then left-right.**

I've tried using flexbox, but there I have to set a fixed width for the container, which just results in the popups being too wide as well.

**Edit for clarification:**
[image: Problem Screenshot]
The dotted line should be the right border for the second popup.
The diagonal lines mark the empty space I need to be gone.

**Edit further approaches:**
Another approach posted by user 'Gobbin' as answer, is to use flex. But as I mentioned, I'd have to set some fixed width. Here it is a max-width for the list itself, so that wrapping works and a fixed width for the list elements. I don't want to have either. Also this approach lists the items from left to right and then from top to bottom, which is also not what I need:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 16em;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

li {
  background-color: lime;
  width: 4em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>entry 1</li>
<li>entry 2</li>
<li>entry 3</li>
<li>entry 4</li>
<li>entry 5</li>
<li>entry 6</li>
<li>entry 7</li>
<li>entry 8</li>
<li>entry 9</li>
<li>entry 10</li>
<li>entry 11</li>
<li>entry 12</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>entry 1</li>
<li>entry 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Highly suggest looking into CSS Grid and CSS Flexbox. They are, quite literally made for this sort of thing

Comment: @TheCrzyMan isn't CSS grid pretty much fixed for column counts and overall widths? And I already mentioned, that with flexbox I have to set a fixed width for the container, so that the items will be in columns.

Comment: Hmm.. Guess I need to read better. Also, why do you need to not display the empty columns? Can you just give the `li` elements the background color?

Comment: @TheCrzyMan these lists are shown in popups, which can be distinguished from the normal background. The background-color in the code snippet here is for visualization only.

Comment: Do you need to have the column count? can you just get rid of it?

Comment: @TheCrzyMan When I use `column-width` I have to set a fixed width for the popups. Then again, when less then 4 entries, the popup is too wide. I've updated my question for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is an option for you, although the columns are spread across the available width.

```js
var maxColumns = 4;
$("ul").each(function() {
  var numColumns = $(this).find("li").length;
  $(this).css("column-count", numColumns);
  $(this).css("width", 25*numColumns + "%");
});
```

```css
ul {
  background-color: lime;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>entry 1</li>
  <li>entry 2</li>
  <li>entry 3</li>
  <li>entry 4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>entry 1</li>
  <li>entry 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And the spreading of the content for the complete width is problematic. :/

Comment: Adjusted taking into account 4 columns is the maximum.

Comment: This is getting an interesting approach. Unfortunately this is no pure CSS solution as requested. But I will look further into this if nothing else pops up!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your desired layout. Edited my answer as the list items still had margins.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
li{
   background-color: lime;
   width: 100%;
   display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>entry 1</li>
<li>entry 2</li>
<li>entry 3</li>
<li>entry 4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>entry 1</li>
<li>entry 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, not what I need. I updated my question for clarification.